# CI jobs spanning multiple stages

Tags: gitlab-ci

How can I create a CI job that spans more than one stage, to improve parallelism?

As in the following diagram:

[image: Diagram showing one process spanning multiple stages]

The idea is that `slow_build` should start as early as `build`, but `test` doesn't depend on it, so `test` should be able to start as soon as `build` is done.

(Note that this is a simplification: each stage has multiple processes running in parallel, otherwise I could just bundle `build` and `test` together.)

Comment: At the moment is not possible, but they are thinking about it, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/41947 

in particular what you are proposing is reported as `Intra and inter stage dependencie`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible as of Gitlab version 12.2. By adding the keyword `needs` to jobs that depend on other jobs, stages can now run concurrently. The full documentation for the `needs` keyword is here, but an example from the docs follows: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs

```
linux:build:
  stage: build

mac:build:
  stage: build

lint:
  stage: test
  needs: []

linux:rspec:
  stage: test
  needs: ["linux:build"]

linux:rubocop:
  stage: test
  needs: ["linux:build"]

mac:rspec:
  stage: test
  needs: ["mac:build"]

mac:rubocop:
  stage: test
  needs: ["mac:build"]

production:
  stage: deploy
```

Since the `lint` job doesn't need anything, it runs instantly, as does `linux:build` and `mac:build`. However, if `linux:build` finishes before `mac:build` then both `linux:rspec` and `linux:rubocop` can start, even before `mac:build` and the `build` stage complete.

As usual, without the `needs` keyword, the `production` job requires all previous jobs to complete before it starts.

When using `needs` in your pipelines, you can also view a Directed Acyclic Graph of your jobs in the pipeline view. More on that can be found here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/directed_acyclic_graph/index.html